# VB.NET DataGridView when I do the search, I would like to exclude the rows that do not have the results I searched for, how to do?

Tags: vb.net, button, search, datagridview, textbox

When I search for a number with my textbox, in the datagridview I find all the results together with the lines that do not have the search result. I would like the datagridview to return me only the rows with the results excluding those not necessary for the search.
How to do?

```
Public Sub FilterData(ValueToSearch As String)
    Try
        Dim SearchQyery As String = "SELECT * FROM LottoDeaBendata WHERE CONCAT_WS([Id],[Data],[Ruota],[Estratto1],[Estratto2],[Estratto3],[Estratto4],[Estratto5])LIKE'%" & ValueToSearch & "%'"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(SearchQyery, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message) 'show error msg'
    End Try
End Sub

   Private Sub btnFiltraDati_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFiltraDati.Click
    FilterData(txtRefreshFiltra.Text)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested to work as expected

```
Private Sub m_Filter() Handles Button1.Click, Me.Shown

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim SearchQuery As String = $"SELECT * FROM dbo.cfgEggTypes WHERE CONCAT(cEggType,cSpecies,cOldEggType, cQBItemAbbr) LIKE '%{txtSearch.Text}%'"
    Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(SearchQuery, SqlConnection)
    Dim SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt)

    dgvExample.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Make sure your SQL query is working as expected in an SQL editor. Set a break point, and copy the exact query text to your sql query editor, and make sure it is correct. If it is correct, your datagridview isn't being cleared properly. You could add  `dgvExample.DataSource = Nothing` to the top of the method to ensure it gets cleared.

Comment: I would recommend changing the above query to the following `SELECT * FROM dbo.cfgEggTypes WHERE CONCAT(cEggType,cSpecies,cOldEggType, cQBItemAbbr) LIKE CONCAT('%',@searchText,'%')` and then adding `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", ValueToSearch)`. You should never put text directly into a query without using parameters.

Comment: Exactly right, but tiny single user desktop apps probably don't contain anything of interest to a hacker :-) Maybe you could provide an example of the above query being hijacked though, just for the sake of learning

Comment: My query works fine, maybe I haven't explained myself well, (GooGle Translator) :) I need to retrieve only the rows where the cells with the search result are found, like, if I search for the number "28", I would like that datagridview would show me only the rows with cells containing the number "28", the other rows must disappear.

Comment: The code I posted above does exactly that. The datagridview ONLY shows the records the query returns